# How to determine if changeset B is a descendant of A?

Tags: mercurial

Given changesets A & B, is there a command to tell if B is a descendant of A?

Assume that B is a descendant of A, but there are many changesets in between.  I'm just trying to get a yes/no answer about this relationship.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer: Use a revset

hg log -r "A and B::"

if you use tortosehg, then use the following in the search window. The parens are key

```
(A and B::)
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe the answer should be:

```
    hg log -r "A:: and B"
```

Or in TortoiseHg (using version 2.8, the parentheses don't seem to be mandatory):

```
    (A:: and B)
```

To interpret the result, you should get the log for B if it is indeed a descendant, and nothing (no match) if it is not.

Sorry, but I could not simply comment on the original answer - lack of reputation.